# Android app to check for login only one time a day

Tags: android, triggers

i need to develop an android app that have a login activity which will force the user must to login one time a day and after login the app will not going to show the login activity.it want to skip the login if user done login successful.on the next day only the app must want to show the login page.can i use Shared Preferences method or database here? how can i implement this!

Comment: You can use shared preferences of SQLite but if the user cleans the app data it will show the login activity again.
On the other hand you can use your server side to save the time of the last login and then decide if the login activity should be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a calendar instance on your splash or main activity and can save it in shared preference to save a date like below--

```
//this is just a reference code
 SharedPreference shared=getSharedPreferences(Preference.KEY_PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor  edit=shared.edit();
        if(!shared.getBoolean(Preference.KEY_FIRST_TIME, false)){
            edit.putBoolean(Preference.KEY_FIRST_TIME,true );
            Calendar first=Calendar.getInstance();
            edit.putLong(Preference.KEY_FIRST_DATE, first.get(Calendar.DATE););
```

1>This can be stored as your last launching date

2>get current date every time app starts and Check if current date = last launching date

3>If they are same then no need to show login else show login and also save current date as last launching date.

that should do it.

Comment: if this is helpful can you please upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

once user login put boolean value login="true" and current date in sharedPreference.

and check for

```
if(currentdate!=storedDate(from sharedPreference) || login(from sharedPreference)=false)
    login required
else
    no need of login
```

Comment: thanks alot Ravi..after seeing ur answer am coming to the point that i can solve this by using sharedPreference..

Answer (score 0):

If user clears app data, `Shared Preference` file data might be lost. You should rather update the login time value on Server to be sure and check that on each Login attempt. Though, you can first check in a `Shared Preference` file by saving the value there too. If value is present in `SP`, you will be saving an API hit.